# Transitioning between multiple storyboards in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have not yet seen this question answered:

What is the best way to implement multiple storyboards in XCode 4? An example of when you would want to do this might be in a team environment where multiple people are working on subsections of the same UI.

Any ideas? I might guess it has to be done manually in code but it would be neat if there were a way to do it graphically within the Storyboard editing view.

Comment: I don't think this is possible graphically.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a link to an example of using multiple storyboards and how to programmatically link multiple Storyboards:  http://www.skillmasters.net/main/?p=193

Here is the author's pertinent sample code:

```
UIStoryboard *settingsStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SettingsStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialSettingsVC = [settingsStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
initialSettingsVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to navigate to a specific view controller then simply use UIViewController *testVC = [(storyboard instance) instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"(Viewcontroller name)"];